# Concatenating two lists but retaining source object information

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I am currently working on a quiz application and have hit a bit of a problem.

I have a User class which gets initiated, and contains two lists of the questions asked, one of their own answers, and one for their answers regarding the other colleagues.

```
public class User
    {
        public List<Answer> AAnswers { get; private set; }
        public List<Answer> BAnswers { get; private set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public User()
        {
            Name = "Player";
            AAnswers = new List<Answer>();
            BAnswers = new List<Answer>();
        }

        public User(string name):this()
        {
            Name = name;
        }
}
```

I then have a class called Quiz, which contains a lot of additional information about the activity. I will just put the key bits of information in.

Inside the class, I use Concat to build two more lists, with every users own and colleague answers combined. Right now I am using a List to store these lists (AllUserAswers and AllColleagueAnsers), however this does not give me access to the users which initially answered the question.

I tried adding adding a User field to the Answer class and constructor, however NewtonSoft kept generating me a Self referencing loop error, so I guess this is not sensible practice.
How would I go about creating maybe a List of Users and Answers. Would I need to use a Tuple or similar? As I am struggling for ideas.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple ways to do this without upsetting your current design too much I think.

You could add a `[JsonIgnore]` to your User property. That would be the quickest and easiest assuming you don't need the json to persist your user.

The other quick solution would be to add an `Id` property to your `User` class. Then in your `Answer` class you could have a `UserId` property.

```
public class User {
    public Guid Id {get;}

    public User() {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}

public class Answer {
    public Guid UserId{get;set;}

    public User User => AllUsers.Single(x => x.Id == UserId);
}
```

Something like that would probably work. I haven't tested it, and it does rely on you having access to AllUsers or something in your Answer class.

Comment: Perfect that was just what I was looking for. I can't do the JsonIgnore as I need the user to persist, but the Guid worked perfectly.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it :)